# How to use value from argument into another argument Django Views

Tags: python, django

I have a view in django

```
def shoplist(request, shop, subcategory, discount, format=None):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['subc'] = ShopSubCategory.objects.get(id = subcategory).category_id
    args['shopfilters'] = Shop.objects.filter(shop_category_id = 'subc')
return render_to_response('shop-catlist.html', args)
```

This view is getting "subcategory" from request (OK)

"subc" getting ID of the category according to the subcategory (OK)

In template it works perfectly, but if I try to use "subc" into "args['shopfilters'} then it gives (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'subc')

How to use 'subc' value as the filter key for 'shopfilters' ?

EDIT

MODELS.PY (important strings)

```
class ShopCategory(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "shop_category"
        verbose_name = "Категория магазина"
        verbose_name_plural = "Категории магазинов"
    section = models.ForeignKey(ShopSection,  blank=False)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length = 100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

class ShopSubCategory(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "shop_subcategory"
        verbose_name = "Подкатегория магазина"
        verbose_name_plural = "Подкатегории магазинов"
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategory,  blank=False)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length = 100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

class Shop(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "shop"
        verbose_name = "магазин"
        verbose_name_plural = "магазины"
    shop_title = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Название магазина", max_length = 150, blank = False)
    shop_text = models.TextField(verbose_name = "Описание магазина", blank=False)
    shop_category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategory, blank=False, verbose_name = "Категория магазина")
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def shoplist(request, shop, subcategory, discount, format=None):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['subc'] = ShopSubCategory.objects.all()
    if subcategory:
        args['subc'] = ShopSubCategory.objects.get(id = subcategory).category_id
    #args['subc'] = '1'
    args['shopfilters'] = Shop.objects.all()
    if subcategory:
        args['shopfilters'] = Shop.objects.filter(shop_category_id = args['subc'])
    args['products'] =  ShopProduct.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    if shop:
        args['products'] = ShopProduct.objects.filter(shop_product_shop_id= shop)
    if subcategory:
        args['products'] = ShopProduct.objects.filter(shop_product_category_id=subcategory)
    if discount:
        args['products'] = ShopProduct.objects.all().exclude(shop_product_price_old__isnull=True).exclude(shop_product_price_old__exact='')
    args['sections'] = ShopSection.objects.all().order_by('name')
    args['categories'] =  ShopCategory.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    args['subcats'] =  ShopSubCategory.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    args['username'] = auth.get_user(request).username
    args['reg_form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('shop-catlist.html', args)
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^store.aspx$', 'shop.views.shop_main'),
    url(r'^productlist.aspx&shop(?P<shop>\d*)&subcategory(?P<subcategory>\d*)&discount(?P<discount>\d*)$', 'shop.views.shoplist'),
)
```

Comment: Have you tried `Shop.objects.filter(shop_category_id = args['subc'])` ?

Comment: You mean: args['subc'] = ShopSubCategory.objects.get(id = subcategory).category_id

Comment: I mean `args['shopfilters'] = Shop.objects.filter(shop_category_id = args['subc'])`

Comment: Yes, I've tried right now, No error message, no effect, cycle is not getting any data

Comment: Is category_id your own field? could you include the relevant parts of your model in your question please?

Comment: And what type of `shop_category_id" is? Are you sure that it is string, not an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `args['subc']` instead of `"subc"` like this:

```
args['shopfilters'] = Shop.objects.filter(shop_category_id = args['subc'])
```

since args['subc'] will contain an Subc id, isn't it?

Comment: So, if {{subc}} is working, looke like somewhere you have `subc` (without quotes) variable. Is the code from question is complete or you skiped something?
Also, could you please show how have you configured url for this view?

Comment: Yes the question is answered, I can give you the link http://open.tm:8080/store/store.aspx The views.py and urls.py i'll add to the question